# css, asp:listview and nth-child

Tags: asp.net, css, listview

I'm trying to learn CSS3 and get away from using table tags.  Working with Visual studio 2010, .net 4.0 and vb.nt in an asp.net project.  I have a listview that i'm trying to get the rows to alternate color.  What i have works but only partially.  What is rendered to screen is several rows that have wrapping text.  The shading is only effecting a small line across the screen.. it does not cover the entire row.  Here is the code:

```
div.row
{
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

div.row:nth-child(1n+3)
{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}


div.row span.label
{
    float: left; /*width: 100px;*/
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.row span.cell
{
    float: left; /*width: 335px;*/
    text-align: left;
}
```

Here is the markup:

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <div class="row" >
                <span class="cell" style="width: 200px;">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="lblCalendarDataID" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "CalendarAddEdit.aspx?ID=" & databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"CalendarDataID")%>'
                        Text='<%# databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"Title")%>' />
                </span>
                <span class="cell" style="width: 150px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate1" runat="server" Text='<%# databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"StartDate1","{0:d}")%>' />
                    -
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate1" runat="server" Text='<%# databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"EndDate1","{0:d}")%>' />
                </span>
                <span class="cell" style="width: 150px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStartTime1" runat="server" Text='<%# databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"StartTime1", "{0:t}")%>' />
                    -
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEndTime1" runat="server" Text='<%# databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"EndTime1", "{0:t}")%>' />
                </span>
                <span class="cell" style="width: 350px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"Description")%>' />
                </span>
                <span class="cell" style="width: 50px;">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlDeleteID" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "CalendarDelete.aspx?ID=" & databinder.eval(container.dataitem,"CalendarDataID")%>'
                        Text="Delete" />
                </span>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

anyone know what i'm doing wrong.  I tried to use the alternatingItemTemplate but could not get it to shade.  In that senerio.. i did a

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: #C0C0C0;">
```

any help would be great.

Comment: What you are doing here doesn't really make sense. You aren't getting away from tables. You are merely using confusing tags to render a table. I say, if you need to display tabular data (anything with a list of rows), go ahead and use your table markup. The only thing you want to avoid using tables for is layout issues. For example, you don't want a menu in one table cell and your page content in another -- use divs for that.

Comment: If you don't want to use a table, use a list (`<ul>`) and float the items (`<li>`).

Answer (score 0):

To have your background shading do what you want, try modifying this style:

```
div.row:nth-child(1n+3)
{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

to be this:

```
div.row:nth-child(1n+3) span
{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

to actually apply the background color to the spans that contain the content.

Comment: thanks for the comment.. i tried this too.. if going to a mobile device.. the table tags can hurt performance.. so i tried this putting everything in a single "cell"... it works.. but it only puts the background color on any text you have.. it doesn't fill in the whole cell like the table tag does... was curious if i'm missig something.. thanks

Comment: what you're describing might be fixed by putting `display:block` on the span "cell"